# Pandas creates DataFrame with first header column in it's own row

Tags: python, pandas, csv, gdelt

I am working with the [GDELT dataset](http://gdeltproject.org/) am having issues creating a pandas `DataFrame` using `pd.DataFrame.from_csv(path_to_data, sep=",")` which seems to load the data fine except except for the fact that the first header column is shifted to row 1 like so:

[image]

The arrow indicates where *Source* should be.  Here is a snippet of the raw data in CSV format:

```
Source,Actor1Type1Code,Actor1Type2Code,Actor1Geo_CountryCode,Target,Actor2Type1Code,Actor2Type2Code,Actor2Geo_CountryCode,EventCode,f0_
PRINCE,GOV,,CA,CITIZEN,CVL,,CA,051,61
MEDIA,MED,,CA,MINIST,GOV,,CA,090,39
SUPREME COURT,JUD,,CA,DOCTOR,HLH,,CA,060,31
POLICE,COP,,CA,TORONTO,,,CA,173,31
PUBLISHER,MED,,CA,BUSINESS,BUS,,CA,010,29
HOSPITAL,HLH,,CA,POLICE,COP,,CA,043,28
HOSPITAL,HLH,,CA,TORONTO,,,CA,043,26
POLICE,COP,,CA,HOSPITAL,HLH,,CA,042,26
PRIME MINISTER,GOV,,CA,GERMANY,,,FR,042,22
```

Thanks!

Calvin

Comment: Yes, I know.  While I see that this is exactly the problem, I won't be able to actually test it until later.  But I will go ahead and accept for now.  Thanks for the response!

Comment: I'm sure that this is the problem as the docs :http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_csv.html#pandas.DataFrame.from_csv show that the default value for `index_col` is `0` so it's treating your first col as the index, setting this to `None` or using `pd.read_csv` will work fine

Comment: Indeed, that was the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `from_csv` it's no longer maintained, use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv):

```
In [244]:

t="""Source,Actor1Type1Code,Actor1Type2Code,Actor1Geo_CountryCode,Target,Actor2Type1Code,Actor2Type2Code,Actor2Geo_CountryCode,EventCode,f0_
PRINCE,GOV,,CA,CITIZEN,CVL,,CA,051,61
MEDIA,MED,,CA,MINIST,GOV,,CA,090,39
SUPREME COURT,JUD,,CA,DOCTOR,HLH,,CA,060,31
POLICE,COP,,CA,TORONTO,,,CA,173,31
PUBLISHER,MED,,CA,BUSINESS,BUS,,CA,010,29
HOSPITAL,HLH,,CA,POLICE,COP,,CA,043,28
HOSPITAL,HLH,,CA,TORONTO,,,CA,043,26
POLICE,COP,,CA,HOSPITAL,HLH,,CA,042,26
PRIME MINISTER,GOV,,CA,GERMANY,,,FR,042,22"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t))
df
Out[244]:
           Source Actor1Type1Code  Actor1Type2Code Actor1Geo_CountryCode  \
0          PRINCE             GOV              NaN                    CA   
1           MEDIA             MED              NaN                    CA   
2   SUPREME COURT             JUD              NaN                    CA   
3          POLICE             COP              NaN                    CA   
4       PUBLISHER             MED              NaN                    CA   
5        HOSPITAL             HLH              NaN                    CA   
6        HOSPITAL             HLH              NaN                    CA   
7          POLICE             COP              NaN                    CA   
8  PRIME MINISTER             GOV              NaN                    CA   

     Target Actor2Type1Code  Actor2Type2Code Actor2Geo_CountryCode  EventCode  \
0   CITIZEN             CVL              NaN                    CA         51   
1    MINIST             GOV              NaN                    CA         90   
2    DOCTOR             HLH              NaN                    CA         60   
3   TORONTO             NaN              NaN                    CA        173   
4  BUSINESS             BUS              NaN                    CA         10   
5    POLICE             COP              NaN                    CA         43   
6   TORONTO             NaN              NaN                    CA         43   
7  HOSPITAL             HLH              NaN                    CA         42   
8   GERMANY             NaN              NaN                    FR         42   

   f0_  
0   61  
1   39  
2   31  
3   31  
4   29  
5   28  
6   26  
7   26  
8   22
```

Or pass param [`index_col=None`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_csv.html#pandas.DataFrame.from_csv):

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(io.StringIO(t), index_col=None)
```

so it doesn't interpret the first column as an index column